# Using the WebCam with the Microsoft Edge Browser

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core, webcam.js

We host an Asp.Net Core 3.1 app in Azure.  Part of our app requires the user to be able to use the camera on their smartphone to take a photo.  We have put in code to accomplish this using the WebcamJS v1.0.25.

This works when we use Chrome, Firefox, and Safari. It works for the Edge Browser on our desktop, but it does not work when we use Edge on our Phone.

how can we make the Edge Browser work on our phone?

```
 function attech_camera() {
        $("#CameraModal").modal({
        backdrop: "static",
        show: true
    });
         Webcam.set({
            width: 300,  
            height: 240,  
            image_format: 'jpeg',  
            jpeg_quality: 100 ,
            constraints: {
                video: true,
                facingMode: "environment"
            }
        });   
    Webcam.attach('#my_camera');
    }
```

Comment: Are you using Android or iPhone devices to access your site? I have checked the WebcamJS official docs but it does not show any information on whether it is supported for mobile devices. Have you tested it on any other mobile browsers and does it work?  I try to test one simple sample of WebcamJS on my Android device and I noticed that the web page shows me an error `WebcamJS is not loaded. when I take the screenshot it shows a black screenshot. Are you getting any errors? I noticed similar issues were reported on their GitHub page. Could you please report your issue over there?

Comment: Thank you for your reply, @Deepak-MSFT,  we have tried Safari, Chrome, Firefox, and Edge on our Apple and Android devices.  It works great on both OS for every browser, except for Edge.  We sometimes get the 'WebcamJS is not loaded' error.  It clears up after another 15 seconds or so.  I saw that similar issues were reported on the WebcamJS GitHub page.  unfortunately, we didn't see any possible solutions to the problem.

Comment: As the mobile browsers don't give detailed error-related information. I would suggest you Try to provide Feedback to Microsoft from the Edge for android browser regarding this issue and from the WebcamJS GitHub page to provide the feedback to their developers.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion.  I will try to find out how to do this.